# Backbone/requireJs and circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, require.js

I'm trying to have a main App view with references of all my views to manage and call transitions between theses views. But, I have circular dependencies.

**app.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/viewOne'

], function ($, _, Backbone, ViewOne) {

    'use strict';
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        views:{},
        ref:'variable test',      
        initialize: function () {

            this.views.viewOne = new myViewOne();

        }
    });

    return AppView;
});
```

**views/viewOne.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'views/app'
], function ($, Backbone, App) {

    'use strict';   
    var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({({

        initialize: function () {
            App = require("views/app");
            console.log(App);   
            //function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
        }

    });

    return ViewOne ;
});
```

I suppose `require()` sends me a string since the module was not called before.

Is an inline function a good approach in this case, and how can I work with it. I've tried this code to fix that, which seems to work.

**app.js**

```
this.views.viewOne = new myViewOne({parentView:this});
```

**views/viewOne.js**

```
var ViewOne = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (ref) {
        this.parentView = ref.parentView;
        console.log(this.parentView.ref);
        //variable test
    }
});
```

Is my approach correct?